# Is the function $f(g(x))$ convex if $f(x)$ is linear and $g(x)$ is convex?

Tags: calculus

I know that if $f(x)$ is a convex function and $g(x)$ is a linear function, then the composition $f(g(x))$ is convex.

But what if $f(x)$ is a linear function and $g(x)$ is a convex function? Would the composition $f(g(x))$ be convex?

Comment: Note that $x\mapsto -x$ is linear

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen How does that information help in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convex iff $g''(x)>0$
$[f(g(x))]'=f'(g(x))g'(x)=cg'(x)$
$[f(g(x))]''=cg''(x)$
Thus convexity depends on the wether the slope of $f$ is positive or negative.
Positive slope would imply curve being convex while negative slope would imply it being concave. This is ofcourse assuming $g$ is twice differentiable